# How to sketch $\sqrt{y^2-1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)$?

Tags: graphing-functions, hyperbolic-functions

> Sketch the graph of $\sqrt{y^2-1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)$ and also of $\sqrt{y^2+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(e^x+e^{-x}\right)$. In each case find an explicit formula for $x$ in terms of $y$.

This is part of an admissions quiz, so unfortunately no access to Desmos or similar. It looks like hyperbolic functions might be involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get from $\sqrt{y^2-1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)$:

$y^2=\cosh^2(x)$. Hence $y=\pm \cosh(x)$.

Comment: $\sqrt{y^2-1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)= \sinh (x)$ gives $y^2-1= \sinh^2 (x)$, hence $y^2=1+ \sinh^2(x)= \cosh^2(x)$.

Comment: Only works for positive values of $x$...